# R conditionally replace values in ordered factor column without losing levels or other attributes

Tags: r

**Background** I am working with numerous, large survey datasets exported from Qualtrics. Each dataset has duplicate questions that are in both spanish and english. The subset of survey questions answered by the participant is determined by their answer to the `lang` question in the survey. The answers to the spanish and english language questions are recorded in different columns in the dataframe. The column names for the spanish answers have the suffix `_sp`.See the example dataframe below

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), lang = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("English / Inglés", "Spanish / Español"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), mob_1 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Strongly agree", "Agree", "Somewhat agree", "Neither agree nor disagree", "Somewhat disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree", NA), class = c("ordered", "factor")), mob_2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A lot worse", "A little worse", "The same", "A little better", "A lot better", NA), class = c("ordered", "factor")), mob_1_sp = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Totalmente de acuerdo", "De acuerdo", "Algo de acuerdo", "Ni de acuerdo ni en desacuerdo", "Algo en desacuerdo", "En desacuerdo", "Totalmente en desacuerdo", NA), class = c("ordered", "factor")), mob_2_sp = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Mucho peor", "Un poco peor", "Igual", "Un poco mejor", "Mucho mejor", NA), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
      id lang              mob_1             mob_2          mob_1_sp              mob_2_sp    
   <dbl> <ord>             <ord>             <ord>          <ord>                 <ord>       
 1     1 English / Inglés  Somewhat disagree A little worse NA                    NA          
 2     2 English / Inglés  Agree             The same       NA                    NA          
 3     3 English / Inglés  Disagree          A little worse NA                    NA          
 4     4 English / Inglés  Strongly agree    The same       NA                    NA          
 5     5 English / Inglés  Disagree          A lot better   NA                    NA          
 6     6 Spanish / Español NA                NA             Algo en desacuerdo    Un poco peor
 7     7 Spanish / Español NA                NA             De acuerdo            Igual       
 8     8 Spanish / Español NA                NA             En desacuerdo         Un poco peor
 9     9 Spanish / Español NA                NA             Totalmente de acuerdo Igual       
10    10 Spanish / Español NA                NA             En desacuerdo         Mucho mejor 

> str(df)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ id      : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ lang    : Ord.factor w/ 2 levels "English / Inglés"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
 $ mob_1   : Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "Strongly agree"<..: 5 2 6 1 6 8 8 8 8 8
 $ mob_2   : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "A lot worse"<..: 2 3 2 3 5 6 6 6 6 6
 $ mob_1_sp: Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "Totalmente de acuerdo"<..: 8 8 8 8 8 5 2 6 1 6
 $ mob_2_sp: Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "Mucho peor"<"Un poco peor"<..: 6 6 6 6 6 2 3 2 3 5
```

**My goal** is to create a flexible loop that will replace the `NA` values in the english language response columns (`mob_1`,`mob_2`) with the values in the spanish language response columns (`mob_1_sp`,`mob_2_sp`) for the spanish language speaking participants, while maintaining the levels of the ordered factor in the english language response column.

I have written the following loop, but when i try to re-assign the levels of the ordered factor back to english language columns the mapping is not consistent. For example:

- row 1, the value of `mob_1` did not change but the level changed from
  `Somewhat disagree` to `Somewhat agree`
- row 6, the labels of `mob_1`
  and `mob_1_sp` do not match even though they have the same values

```
for (i in colnames(df)) {
  if(grepl("_sp", i)) {
    eng_var <- gsub("_sp","",i) #get name of english variable equivalent
    levels(df[[i]]) <- levels(df[[eng_var]]) #assign english levels to spanish variable 
    df[[eng_var]] = as.ordered(ifelse(df$lang=="Spanish / Español",as.numeric(df[[i]]),df[[eng_var]])) #conditionally replace values of english variable
    levels(df[[eng_var]]) <-  levels(df[[i]]) #re-assign english levels from spanish variable
  }
}

> df
# A tibble: 10 x 6
      id lang              mob_1                      mob_2          mob_1_sp          mob_2_sp      
   <dbl> <ord>             <ord>                      <ord>          <ord>             <ord>         
 1     1 English / Inglés  Somewhat agree             A lot worse    NA                NA            
 2     2 English / Inglés  Agree                      A little worse NA                NA            
 3     3 English / Inglés  Neither agree nor disagree A lot worse    NA                NA            
 4     4 English / Inglés  Strongly agree             A little worse NA                NA            
 5     5 English / Inglés  Neither agree nor disagree The same       NA                NA            
 6     6 Spanish / Español Somewhat agree             A lot worse    Somewhat disagree A little worse
 7     7 Spanish / Español Agree                      A little worse Agree             The same      
 8     8 Spanish / Español Neither agree nor disagree A lot worse    Disagree          A little worse
 9     9 Spanish / Español Strongly agree             A little worse Strongly agree    The same      
10    10 Spanish / Español Neither agree nor disagree The same       Disagree          A lot better
```

I think the issue with the level mapping is that there are 8 levels in the survey response, but only 4 unique values in my reproducible dataframe.

I would appreciate any help in pointing out where I went wrong, and if there is a way to just insert the spanish language column values into the english language columns without messing with the column attributes.

Comment: How would you add values from `mob_1_sp` in `mob_1` without changing the ordered factor levels? Since levels in  `mob_1_sp` are not present in `mob_1` initially.

Comment: @RonakShah The levels in `mob_1_sp` are identical to `mob_1` except they are in spanish vs. english

Comment: I don't think R knows that the levels are the same and the only difference is Spanish vs English.

Comment: @RonakShah agreed, but since the ordered value for the factor between the english and spanish columns are the same in the original dataset(e.g. the label for `mob_1 == 1L` is `"Strongly agree"`, and the label for `mob_1_sp == 1L` is `"Totalmente de acuerdo"` (spanish translation of "strongly agree") can i just insert the numeric values of `mob_1_sp` into `mob_1` without removing the levels/labels of `mob_1`?